# Migrating VS2012 Project to VS2022 ==> Getting Linking errors, seems that directory can't properly parsed

Tags: visual-c++, dll, linker, visual-studio-2022

I migrate a VS2012 proj into VS2022 proj and was able to solve a lot of problems. I'm in the last step which makes me trouble. It looks like that the linker can't parse the directory for specific dll's properly.

[image]

Any advise will be welcome.
Thnx DJ

Comment: I don't think it is enough to show a screen grab. You must have some custom build steps there and ideally you should paste those steps as code into your question. Something must be amiss there I guess.